# Most readable way of generic views placement

Tags: design, python, object-oriented-design, django

What are your suggestions on placing many generic views?
Let's consider a classic situation where I have many generic views for CRUD for given models. What is the best way to place them in `views.py`?

Proposition #1 (`views.py`):

```
class FooCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Foo
    ...

class FooListView(ListView):
    model = Foo
    ...

class FooDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Foo
    ...

class BarCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Bar
    ...

class BarListView(ListView):
    model = Bar
    ...

class BarDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Bar
    ...
```

The above proposition segments views based on models which are involved in them. But maybe the following system is better?

Proposition #2 (`views.py`):

```
class FooCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Foo
    ...

class BarCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Bar
    ...

class FooListView(ListView):
    model = Foo
    ...

class BarListView(ListView):
    model = Bar
    ...

class FooDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Foo
    ...

class BarDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Bar
    ...
```

In that way there is a grouping of views based on their types/purposes - firstly the creation views, then list views, and then detail views.

Another idea is to create a `views/foo.py` and `views/bar.py` for which there are only views that involves given models.

What are your practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related code should be vertically close. You have the situation where, depending on how you look at it, different classes are related in different ways. I think the driving force here is the model and so I would put views related to a specific model in their own files `views/foo.py` `views/bar.py`.